# Button Vs clickable image that looks like button

Tags: android

Another android question. What is more efficient of common, having a START button on the screen and trying to customize this button or having a clickable image view with the image of start (clicked and not clicked)?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Customizing a `Button` is not hard. Check out [state list](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList).

I guess using `Button` is better because of accessibility.